# Unable to seek beyond 16776 seconds

Tags: actionscript-3, netstream

I have a custom player that plays back voice recordings (only audio). If the audio file is long the NetStream class does not seek it well. I found out that after 16776 seconds (04:39:36), the NetStream seek function starts again from the beginning of the file. Here is the shortest pseudo code:

```
package com.name.player
{
    import flash.net.NetConnection;
    import flash.net.NetStream;
    ...

    public class StreamingPlayer extends Sprite
    {
        public var maStream:NetStream;
        ...

        public function aFunction
        {
            maStream = new NetStream( maConnection );
            maStream.inBufferSeek = true; // ==> Generates compile error: 
            //Error: Access of possibly undefined property inBufferSeek through a reference with static type flash.net:NetStream.
            //    [mxmlc] 
            //    [mxmlc]             maStream.inBufferSeek = true;
            //    [mxmlc]                      ^

            maStream.play('sName', 0, -1, true);
            // Now try these (one at a time)
            maStream.seek(16775); // Seeks to the desired position and plays the file till the end
            maStream.seek(16776); // Seeks at second 0 ( begining )
            maStream.seek(16778); // Seeks at second 0 ( begining )
            maStream.seek(16780); // Seeks at second 3
            maStream.seek(16786); // Seeks at second 9
            maStream.seek(16796); // Seeks at second 19
            ...

        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I tried different formats (speex, wav) / codes / bit rate:
 - RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, ITU G.711 A-law, mono 8000 Hz
 - RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 16 bit, mono 44100 Hz
 - Ogg data, Speex audio

The file size or total length does not matter, I tried between 1.1 - 1500 MB and between 04:40:00 (17000 seconds) to 14:56:41 (53801 seconds).

I am using html5 for new browsers, but we still need to have support for older browsers (on some client PC's that cannot be updated of install new software, so I need a flash solution for those, because Flash is already installed and running along side IE6 :( ).

Q:
*Do I do something wrong or there is a limitation in NetStreamer, and if there is what solution(s) do I have to be able to play these long files ?*

P.S. This is my first time working with flash, so please try to be a little more explicit if you have an answer/comment.

**EDIT:** Added bug at Adobe ID 3492103.

**EDIT:**
I have a colleague testing the stream server and he found something intersting the the log:

```
// This is lower than 16776 seconds, and works
01-26 13:02:14.277  RtmpProtocol:891        [ID-007] Seeking to 1594380
...
01-26 13:02:14.279  FileReaderWav:194       [ID-007] <Stream0001> Seeking to 15943804 sf_seek 127550432
...
01-26 13:02:16.250  FileReaderWav:230       [ID-007] <Stream0001> Current position: 15943824

// This is when it plays from the beginning (seeking after 16776 seconds)
// according to the log it should just play at the desired position, but it's not
01-26 13:02:23.294  RtmpProtocol:891        [ID-007] Seeking to 16990012
01-26 13:02:23.303  FileReaderWav:194       [ID-007] <Stream0001> Seeking to 16990012 sf_seek 135920096
01-26 13:02:23.463  FileReaderWav:230       [ID-007] <Stream0001> Current position: 16990032
```

We migth have a problem in the stream server, some INTEGER casting or something like that. I will update if I get more info.

**Thank you**

Comment: Theres nothing in the docs to suggest 17000+ is not an acceptable value and there are no bugs logged for NetStream.seek(). Perhaps you've discovered a new one? I doubt many users have tried to play such long files before

Comment: @LeeBurrows There are any ways I can fill in a bug ? AFAIK flash is more or less dead from a development point of view, but nevertheless I think should let them know.

Comment: bugs can be filed here: https://bugs.adobe.com/. And Flash certainly isnt dead; Flash websites maybe, but not flash itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to consider if the file is fully buffered to the desired seek position.  If you are trying to **STREAM** a file (aka not fully loaded) and seek to a position of the file thats not fully loaded... it will generate an error, or just not go there.

SOLUTIONS:

(1) ensure the file is buffered to that position before seeking

(2) use PHP (or any server side) to serve you the file **AT** the desired point.  This will save you tones on bandwidth as only the requested data will be passed.

Eg. If you're requested file is 1500mb, but you only need 800-1500mb... then serve the file at the position.

Comment: I generated a 1.1 Mb ogg file, that easily fits in the buffer, and I have the same problem at the exact same second. I tend to believe that it's a bug in NetStream, that won't be fixed taking in consideration that flash is more or less dead.

Comment: @RaduMaris Flash is far from dead, I'm not sure about the update procedure with Apache, but I'm sure they are quite capable of dealing with issues/updates.  To your question, it could very well be a bug.  Personally I tend to split files and serve chunks (to save bandwidth) so I have not come across this.  But I will test this tonight and let you know my findings.  Also try [inBufferSeek], its a method of NetStream which should tell you if the data is buffered for "smart" stream (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html)

Comment: I have an error trying inBufferSeek "Error: Access of possibly undefined property inBufferSeek through a reference with static type flash.net:NetStream". I updated the code to see where and how the netStream is defined. Disclaimer: I did not build the player and it's my first time I am using flash :)

Comment: @RaduMaris what sdk version are you using?

Comment: None. I am using a simple text editor, and the compile is done with ant, mxmlc using Flex 3.4 on a Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS. I am checking the stream server now. See updated question.

Comment: Ahh... therein lies some of your problems.  3.4 is a really old SDK - with its own problems.  You can still use Flex, but I suggest you download the most recent SDK from Adobe (4.6) or Apache (4.9).  Updat the Flex SDK base and you will now have access to "extra" classes, methods/properties.  After you do this, let me know the outcome.  Main reason is, many classes have changed between 3.4 and 4.6 - MANY.

Comment: I will discuss the update with my team, and I will let you know of the outcome, it can take a few days/weeks. For now I will close the question and I will drop you a comment if I will have new info. Thank you for all.

Comment: @RaduMaris no problem.  Just send me a comment.  Cheers.